# Cannot create sell order: Python ccxt binance does not have market symbol USDT/BTC

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, ticker, binance-api-client, ccxt

I am using python ccxt module to create a sell order in some binance account. First I create the exchange client

```
import ccxt
exchange = ccxt.binance( { 'apiKey' : "<someKey>" , 'secret' : "<thaSecretKey>" } )
```

Then when I try to use its `create_market_sell_order` method to create a market sell order I get the following error:

```
>>> exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol="USDT/BTC", amount="0.1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
    raise BadSymbol(self.id + ' does not have market symbol ' + symbol)
ccxt.base.errors.BadSymbol: binance does not have market symbol USDT/BTC
```

So seems like there is no ticker for selling USDT for BTC, while it works for the BTC/USDT ticker.

**How could I create a sell order to buy BTC with USD using this `create_market_sell_order` method?** The same happens with MANA: there are no `'<someCrypto>/MANA'` tickers!

```
ccxt.base.errors.BadSymbol: binance does not have market symbol BTC/MANA
```

So I can neither sell MANA.

I don't want to create a buy order instead because calculating the amount I could buy with my available USDT is not straightforward.

Comment: "because calculating the amount I could buy with my available USDT is not straightforward." But you already had to specify the amount for the sell order, rather than someone else calculating it from an account balance? If you simply do the math from the amount you want to sell and a current market-rate quote, is that not sufficient? Why not?

Comment: In the sell order, I already know how much I have to sell, but in the buy order I do not know how much I could buy. The thing is that if I want to buy with all my holding and if the amount is large it is not easy to do the math with the current market-rate quote since it may change during the selling process. Moreover, why would such ticker not exist? That is the essence of this question.

Comment: "if I want to buy with all my holding" this was not clear because the example shows a hard-coded, round number for the amount.

Comment: Suppose the amount is `amount= exchange.fetch_balance()['BTC']['free']` so I want to sell all of it.

Comment: I think you are confused as to what the tickers represent. Binance has a number of trading pairs available such as BTC/USDT but it doesn't have a USDT/BTC or a BTC/MANA trading pair. They just don't offer that product pure and simple. You can't make trading pair products up just by combining their name with a slash in between.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `"USDT/BTC"` to `"BTC/USDT"`.

`"BTC/USDT"` means the amount USDT per 1 BTC
and `"USDT/BTC"` means the amount of BTC per 1 USDT

Comment: The aim of this question is to create a sell order. Of course I can replace the ticker and create a buy order but then I also have to calculate how much I can buy and precisely that is what I want to skip... Moreover Why, for example, "BTC/MANA" does not exist?